# For the category_playlists function in Spotipy API, which categories show up when using the country parameter?

Tags: spotipy

I'm assuming that using the country parameter in `category_playlists(category_id=None, country=None, limit=20, offset=0)` returns the top n (limit) number of playlists in that category for a certain country. Is that true? Or are the playlists ordered in some way other than popularity?

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the playlists are returned is the same as what you can see in the Browse section in the Spotify client, and it is not necessarily ordered by popularity. Here's an example for the "Pop" category and Italy as country:

```py
for i in spotify.category_playlists("pop",country="IT")['playlists']['items']:
        print(i['name'])
```

This command returns:

- Big Italiani
- Hot Hits Italia
- Alta Rotazione
- Generazione Z
- Hit Internazionali
- Today's Top Hits
- Hit Italiane
- New Music Friday Italia

which corresponds to what you can see on the client (note the amount of followers is not in a descending order):

[image]